Dask: In-place Modification with Boolean Indexing Causing Unexpected Behavior
I would like to do an in-place bitwise operation on my dask array i, with a mask cover it.
MVE:
import dask.array as da
i = da.full((10,10),fill_value=4)
c = da.ones(i.shape, dtype=bool)
c[:,0] = False # For some variety
i[c] |= da.full(i.shape, fill_value=2)
i[c]

my expected output would be
array([[6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
       [6, 6, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]])

but meanwhile I get the error: ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (nan,) (10, 10)
How could I do in place bitwise operations, with a mask, on a dask array

da.where(c, i, i | 2).compute()

This also follows the philosophy of keeping dask.arrays immutable

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
